# return unknown size string from argument function in c

Tags: c

I have a function and want to return the unknown size string from function arguments like that:

```
int encrypt(const char *input, char *output)
{
     output_len = generate_random(); // random output size
     ...
     output = malloc(output_len);
     memcpy(output, data, output_len);
     return 0;
}
```

when I call the function like below `out_buffer` is not change and is `null`

```
char *out_buffer;
encrypt(in_buffer, out_buffer);
```

I change my code and use the pointer to pointer like this:

```
int encrypt(const char *input, char **output)
{
     output_len = generate_random(); // random output size
     ...
     *(output) = malloc(output_len);
     memcpy(output, data, output_len);
     return 0;
}
....
char *out_buffer;
encrypt(in_buffer, &out_buffer);
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is not working? I'm afraid `input` argument is never used inside the function and you are not returning `output_len` from the function.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. The problem could be anything.

Comment: After changing `char *output` to `char **output`, you need to use `*output` everywhere in the function, e.g. `*output = malloc(...)` and `memcpy(*output, ...)`

Comment: @user3386109 I forgot it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put a `*` before `output` here:

```
memcpy(*output, data, output_len);
//     ^
```

The program compiled without errors/warnings because `memcpy` takes a `void` pointer and any pointer type is compatible with `void*`.

**Bonus hint**

Dont write `*(output)` but just `*output`. Though having the parenthesis is not wrong, but just odd.